# pytorch different versions with "pip3 show torch" VS "torch.__version__"

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

When checking the installed pytorch version you can do that in two ways:

- `pip3 show torch` (or similar `python3 -m pip freeze` for all packages)
- `import torch; torch.__version__`

Interestingly the first option (using `pip3`) returns `1.8.1+cu111`, while the second option (`torch.__version__`) returns `1.7.1` (without the cuda version support string, but cuda is available).

Why do these two methods show different results and which one is the "valid" one?

**Important**
When I installed pytorch with cuda support I installed the latest version, but downgraded a few weeks ago for different reasons.

Some info:

- OS: ubuntu
- python installed natively (not in conda, also not using jupyter)

Comment: You likely have two versions installed. `pip uninstall torch==1.7.1` and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I had even more versions installed. I'll uninstall all of them and install only the correct version.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. If you make an answer out of your comment I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when you have multiple versions of the same library installed for some reason (normally mixing `conda install` and `pip install` in my experience). I recommend uninstalling oldest versions using the appropriate package manager until you see the expected behavior.